# How to make ls warning me about parent directory is symlink

Tags: bash, ls, symlink

I just found a scenario which i (**or someone new to linux**) might accidentally rm file because user thought it's duplicated file. Let's say i have this two binary files:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$ ls -larthi /bin/seltr2
1054051 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 3.4K Oct 30 22:54 /bin/seltr2*
[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$ ls -larthi /usr/bin/seltr2
1054051 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 3.4K Oct 30 22:54 /usr/bin/seltr2*
```

Normally i wouldn't look at inode is same, i just look at the right hand side have **-> sign** or not. So the problem arise if /bin is symlink to /usr/bin:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$ ls -larthi /bin
16 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 Nov 18  2014 /bin -> usr/bin/
```

So if user thought the file is not symlink and no different, user might rm it:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$ sudo rm /bin/seltr2
```

And finally realize that /usr/bin/seltr2 is same file and ask the rescue:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$ ls /usr/bin/seltr2
/home/xiaobai/ls: cannot access /usr/bin/seltr2: No such file or directory
```

So is there any simple way make **ls take account of parent directory is a symlink**, e.g:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$ ls -larthi /bin/seltr2
1054051 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 3.4K Oct 30 22:54 /bin/seltr2* -> /usr/bin/seltr2*
```

I'm not always look at inode number. Is there better way to avoid this kind of potential mistake ?

Comment: Most people don't manually remove files from /bin, /usr/bin and similar system directories.  I think as you become more experienced you will learn and remember more and more, and as you do you will understand the "landscape" and how to move around and exist in unix/linux.  Usually, interactive `ls` command is set to colorize file names by file type, however this is only based on the last element in the path.  I'm not aware of a version which colorizes each item in the path.  Also, you should be doing this kind of activity only in your home directory where you know what's going on.

Comment: Users who don't know what they're doing shouldn't be given root privileges.

Comment: @Barmar The example is just for demonstration, it can happen on anywhere which user thought the files is redundant/duplicated and remove it, only after realized one of its parent directory is symlink which was unable to figure out by simply `ls -l`. It's potential risks, not tied to root or system directories.

Comment: More generally, people shouldn't be deleting files just because they happen to have the same name, unless they're sure of what they're doing. If they know the context of the files, they should know whether the directories are likely to be linked or not.

Comment: One problem is that if there are *n* symlinks in a path (including symlinks to symlinks), you can have as many as 2 ^ *n* different alternative paths to display. If you can simplify the question to something like "is there a command to tell whether two paths are the exact same file?", there are a couple of solutions for that.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with ordinary users not having root priviledges.

Thanks for your comment - now I understand the question - I've re-edited this post

```
root@host:~# ls -latr /bin/test-dir
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov  4 12:01 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  4 12:02 testfile
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  4 12:02 .
root@host:~# ls -latr /usr/bin/test-dir-link
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Nov  4 12:03 /usr/bin/test-dir-link -> /bin/test-dir
root@host:~# rm /usr/bin/test-dir-link
root@host:~# ls -latr /bin/test-dir
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov  4 12:01 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  4 12:02 testfile
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  4 12:02 .
root@host:~# ls -latr /usr/bin/test-dir-link
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/test-dir-link: No such file or directory
```

As you can see above - it has only deleted the "symlink" but not "target".

Also there seems to be a typo-mistake in your files - **your symlink points to "usr/bin" BUT it should be "/usr/bin".**

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: No, it still shows `rm: remove regular file ‘/bin/seltr2’?`

Comment: @林果皞. This should work. Have you got the alias setup in your root's .bashrc (if its bash shell) or appropriate *shrc.

Comment: My rm is /usr/bin/rm, not alias. Are you sure understand my question properly ? The problem is parent directory is a symlink, but its content/individual file is not directly point to symlink, instead it's indirect act like a symlink just because its parent directory is a symlink.

Comment: `usr/bin` will work fine in this case - the content of the symlink is a relative path and the thing it will be relative to is the directory that contains the symlink i.e. `/` ... the result will be the same as using `/usr/bin`, except that the code in the kernel will not have to reset back to the root to find the destination (no difference in this case, but if you were a hundred levels down into a filesystem it could make quite a big difference)